# Flash movie has issues with parallax technique

Tags: flash, parallax

I have created a site using the **parallax technique**. I have used a transparent flash movie with animation on the front parallax layer and when the mouse curson is on top of  the movie the screen seems *to tremble* in contrast to the rest of the site in which the move seems much more smoother. I am not sure if is has anything to do with the size of the movie. *It has a width of 1450px and a height of 825px*.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide an URL or some code?